# Raspberry Pi 3 Always booting to terminal

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to working with a Pi, I'm setting up a machine in a headless configuration but have been having issues getting the GUI to display when i use VNC to connect to the Pi.

It seems that after a reboot the Pi sits at the terminal, pressing enter on a connected keyboard then starts the GUI and all is fine.

Does anyone know how i can stop it sitting at the terminal so it boots straight to the GUI?

Comment: (i have already set boot to desktop in the Pi config btw and it doesn't stop it sitting at the terminal until i press enter)

Comment: Have you tried connecting an external screen to see if it asks for anything?

Comment: Yeah when i connect a screen it's just sat in a terminal window, if i then press enter on a connected keyboard it will finish booting to the GUI. The problem is that if i reboot remotely i then can't access the GUI via VNC until i physically have access to the pi again to be able to press enter.

Comment: Any other suggestions or help greatly appreciated.